# Apache2 conf Redirect everything to HTTPS except one path

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect everything on my WordPress-site to HTTPS except one url, http://example.com/woocommerce/callback/ but I cant get it to work.

This is my apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !woocommerce/callback
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

    DocumentRoot /mnt/persist/www/

    <Directory /mnt/persist/www/>
       Require all granted
       AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But it still redirects to HTTPS for http://example.com/woocommerce/callback/

Comment: Try with:  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^woocommerce/callback/?$`

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work :(